# Elastic search query string shows documents that do not have specified key

Tags: elasticsearch

In version 6.7.1 elastic search, I am using the query string to get some documents. After executing the query string, in addition to the actual documents, it gives those documents also which does not have the key against which data is filtered.
This was not the case when I was using 6.4.2 elastic version. The official site does not have any information regarding that.

My query looks like - 
"* AND ( properties.foreignKeys.referenceTableId :(file_datatypes) OR properties.primaryKeyMetadata.referenceTables :(file_datatypes) )". 
It shows the documents that has properties.foreignKeys: null and properties.primaryKeyMetadata: null, in json

Any update will be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the query you're sending.

Comment: properties.tags :abc. It gives those documents also where properties.tags does not exist in json documents.

Comment: You need to explain a bit more your context. Are you querying through Kibana (Discover or Dev Tools), or through a client, etc? Help us help you and provide as much information as possible...

Comment: Yes agreed please explain us in brief

Comment: Thanks, Val and Kartheek for your help. I have tested with Kibana as well as high-level java Rest client. It does not make any difference. Please kindly let me know if you need any further information. In 6.4.2 when I was using same query, I was only getting valid documents that had those key value pair.

Comment: @Abinash it would be more clear if you add the query and a sample doc that you expect and also a sample doc which you don't expect but is returned by the query.

Comment: Exact query looks like - "* AND (  properties.foreignKeys.referenceTableId :(file_datatypes) OR properties.primaryKeyMetadata.referenceTables :(file_datatypes) )". It shows the documents that has properties.foreignKeys: null and properties.primaryKeyMetadata: null, in json.

Comment: Added the query which differs in output for Elastic version 6.6.2 and 6.4.2.

Comment: Just for information, it is happening with v6.7.1 also so I updated the version in my question.